# How do Rails Devs Handle Model/Default Value Issues Post Launch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for some advise on the following:

1. You have an app live with customers and real data
2. While developing new features, you need to add a column to lets say the projects table
3. This new column is a UID of some type which is generating by the model using a before_save

This all works fine for new projects moving forward. But all existing projects are nil for that column and everything breaks.

How do you handle his in the Rails world?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be handled within the migration script, rather than a Rake task.

If I understand correctly, it'll only ever need to be performed once, at the time the column is added to historical records. In my mind, a migration script shouldn't leave the app with a broken data set. Migrations are designed for more than just schema changes.

Here's an example:

```
def self.up
  change_table :projects do |t|
    t.integer 'new_column'
  end

  Project.reset_column_information

  Project.all.each do |project|
    project.new_column = some_value
    project.save
  end
end
```

The reset_column_information method makes Rails aware of the new column you just added.

Comment: I like this clean. Less to remember on a deployment, seems safer. Thank you Steve.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create a rake task that pulls in all projects without a UID and and one to each project.

After you run the migration run the task. All of your projects should now have a UID.

Comment: Agreed.  If this is a one time thing, I usually just put the code that you would have in the rake task directly in the migration, since it is so closely related to the migration.  Alternately, if you allow the nil values for this column, then you change the parts of your app that reference this column and handle it appropriately (check for nil).

Comment: Thanks all. I'm new so this is helpful, though there doesn't seem to be any tutorials on this topic via Google.... Where in the rails dir does one store the rake tasks so that I can run them on Heroku? Also, any way you'd be able to update your answer showing the basic structure or layout for a rake task?

Comment: Steve's answer is spot on. Wish I had thought of that before. If you ever do find yourself in a position where you need a custom rake task for something (and you probably will at some point) you should take a look at this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks